# Align table content at end position of its title

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I need to create a table header centered and its values must be right-aligned and start right on the header's last character.

**Example**:

[image]

Any ideas to do it? I've found a way that requires to know the size of the header, but it requires to have known sizes for every resolution.

Comment: show your code is here

Answer (score 0):

you will need 3 columns, either 3 tds or 1 td + pseudo elements turned into table-cell .

For a flex or grid layout, you will also need 3 columns to start from.

ex:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: dashed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%)
}

tr:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) {
  border: dashed
}

tr:before,
tr:after {
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%
}

td {
  padding: 0.45em;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%)
}


/* ==== flex , not use ===*/

section {
  display: flex;
  border: dashed;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%)
}

section:before,
section:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
}

p:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 32.5%;
  top: 32.5%;
  border-top: dashed;
  border-bottom: dashed
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%)
}


/*===== grid ======*/

body>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  border: dashed;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%);
  position: relative;
}

p {
  grid-column: 2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption><code>Table-layout</code></caption>
  <tr>
    <td>column name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>column </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<code>flex</code>, too verbose to be useful
<section>
  <div>
    <p>column name</p>
    <p>column </p>
    <p> name </p>
  </div>
</section>

<code>grid</code>, efficient enough.
<div>
  <p>column name</p>
  <p>column </p>
  <p> name </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to wrap the text (`.td-content`) with some padding div (`.fixed-padding`) for this. The trick is to only add the padding to the right in the non-header cells and align them with `margin-left: auto`.

Here is some example table:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="td-content">
          <div class="fixed-padding"></div>
          <div class="th-text">Some Title Text</div>
          <div class="fixed-padding"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="td-content">
          <div class="td-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
          <div class="fixed-padding"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="td-content">
          <div class="td-text">Lorem ipsum</div>
          <div class="fixed-padding"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="td-content">
          <div class="td-text">Lorem</div>
          <div class="fixed-padding"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the css to go with it:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.th-text {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.td-text {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.td-content {
  display: flex;
}

.fixed-padding {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Try on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ziale/pen/bGePyyq)